# Hidden parent navigator header in child screen

Tags: react-native, nested, header, hidden, react-native-navigation

I'm a newbie to React Native, working on a class project. I want to build a chat app and create screen navigation similar to a messaging app. My navigation structure looks like this:

MainDrawerNavigator:
MainBottomTabNavigator:
Tab1-ChatStackNavigator:
CurrentChatScreen
ChatScreen
ChatConfigScreen
Tab2-AnotherStack...
...
I want to hide the MainDrawerNavigator in the ChatScreen, ChatConfig, and so on, but not in the CurrentChatScreen. Is there a solution for this?

I've attempted two solutions:

1. I tried using a modal, but its performance wasn't satisfactory.
2. I set an ID for the MainDrawerNavigator and then used useNavigation().getParent(id) in the ChatScreen to set the options: { headerShown: false }. However, this approach also suffered from performance issues, and it didn't display the drawer header until the ChatScreen was unmounted.

Comment: Please add some code, to make it more clear what you are trying to do, and where you are going wrong. Also try the docs/tutorials on nested navigation: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/